# Number to german decimal format converter function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, formatting, integer

I have a function that formats a number (even a float) to a  German decimal format. I got this function from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript and it works. But every time I want to format a number that I stored in a variable I have to add `.format(2, 3, '.', ',')`.

EX: I have an int :45122.9 and I want to format it I have this function:

```
Number.prototype.format = function(n, x, s, c) {
    var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + (x || 3) + '})+' + (n > 0 ? '\\D' : '$') + ')',
        num = this.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~n));

    return (c ? num.replace('.', c) : num).replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&' + (s || ','));
};
var netto=45122.9;
document.write(netto.format(2, 3, '.', ',')+ ' ' +'€');
```

This will format my number as such `45.122,90  €`.

Is there a way to name the function, let´s say... "formatNumber", add this part to it `format(2, 3, '.', ',')` and than just call it like this: `document.write(formatNumber(netto));` ?

Comment: Did or didn't you write this code yourself? Is the indentation intentional or a copy-paste error?

Comment: I already said I have the code from stackoverflow and the indentation is a copy-paste error.

Comment: Aside from making it better, which I think there is room for improvement in terms of readability, I would suggest placing it in it's own CurrencyFormatter class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: @Nolo I do not know what you mean

Comment: Also, assuming it is only to be used for currency formatting, the first two arguments are implied, so they may be removed - fixed decimal places and digit grouping are always 2 and 3 respectively for currency formatting (AFAIK).

Comment: The SO QA link I posted talks about why it's not a good idea to add functions to the prototype chain of native objects.  This function should stand alone or be grouped with other functions in a class that handles currency formatting.

Comment: What happens if someone passes `',99}\\'` as `x` to your function? It really would mess up your formatting, I suspect

Answer (score 3):

For formatting currency, given that there are many desired formats, the easiest and most readable way is to just make a function called `formatCurrency()` that might look something like this:

```
function formatCurrency(amount, symbol, groupDigits, preFixed, exchangeCommas){
    var result = amount.toFixed(2);
    if(groupDigits){
        result = result.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
    }
    if(prefixed){
        result = symbol + result;
    }else{
        result = result + symbol;
    }
    if(exchangeCommas){
        var decimalIndex = result.lastIndexOf(".");
        result = result.replace(",", ".");
        result = result.substring(0, decimalIndex) + "," + result.substring(decimalIndex + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467433/currency-formatting-in-javascript

Edit: Note that the parameters `groupDigits`, `preFixed` and `exchangeCommas` are optional boolean values.

Then if you want to make it shorter or less readable for whatever reason there are online tools that make it easy to do so, such as [yui compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

```js
/**
 * Formats given number according to given options.
 * @param {number} number The number to be formatted.
 * @param {!Object.<string, *>} options The formatting options.
 * @return {string} The formatted number string.
 */
function formatNumber(number, options) {
  /** @type {Array.<string>} */
  var result = (options['fraction'] ? number.toFixed(options['fraction']) :
                                      '' + number).split('.');
  return options['prefix'] +
      result[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,
      /** @type {string} */ (options['grouping'])) +
      (result[1] ? options['decimal'] + result[1] : '') +
      options['suffix'];
}

// Example:
var expected = '45.122,90 €';
var number = 45122.9;
var formatted = formatNumber(number, {
  'decimal': ',',
  'grouping': '.',
  'fraction': 2,
  'prefix': '',
  'suffix': ' €'
 });


alert('Formatted: ' + formatted + '\n' +
      'Expected: ' + expected + '\n' +
      'Equals: ' + (formatted == expected));
```

Source: https://github.com/Datamart/Glize/blob/master/src/formatters/NumberFormatter.js#L22